# Arduino turn the LED on and off but not for equal timelapses without using delay

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to write a code for Arduino which will turn on the LED for 1 second, then keep it off for 5 seconds and then turn it back on for 1 second and so on, and I need to do this without using delay() function.

I found the following code

```
if( (currentMils - prevMils_for_2) > interval_for_2 )
  {
    prevMils_for_2 = currentMils;



    if(state_for_2 == LOW)
      state_for_2 = HIGH;
    else
      state_for_2 = LOW;


      digitalWrite(2, state_for_2);
  }
```

that makes the LED blink without using delay() but I cant figure out how can I apply this technique if on and off times are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can change *interval_for_2* value:

```
if((currentMils - prevMils_for_2) > interval_for_2 ){
    prevMils_for_2 = currentMils;
    if(state_for_2 == LOW){
      state_for_2 = HIGH;
      interval_for_2 = 1000;// duration for high
    }
    else{
      state_for_2 = LOW;
      interval_for_2 = 2000;// duration for low
    }
    digitalWrite(2, state_for_2);
}
```